# Total direct image under submersion

Tags: sheaf-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $f: X \to B$ be a smooth fiber bundle with fiber $F$, and assume that $B$ is simply connected. Then higher direct images $R^p f_*(\mathbb R_X)$ are naturally isomorphic to the constant sheaves with fiber $H^p(F, \mathbb R)$.

I would like to consider also total derived functors, where leads to the question: is there a nice quasi-isomorphism representative of the total direct image $Rf_*(\mathbb R_X)\in D^+(Sh(B))$? Can we somehow explicity compute if we know enough information about $f$?

I think, I can prove that in general, $Rf_* (\mathbb R_X)$ might **not** be quasi-isomorphic to a complex of constant sheaves, because any such complex is also quasi-isomorphic to its cohomology, which is not true for total direct image in general. This (in a way) corresponds to Leray-Serre spectral sequence having non-trivial differentials.

Comment: Nice question. I would be interested in an answer even in a particular case, say the Hopf fibration. Well, you can always find representatives with Mayer-Vietoris, but this is not very satisfying.

Comment: Maybe I should remove my previous comment. I just realized that you were working with $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients. In that case, you have the De Rham complex. This helps in constructing some representative in particular cases (like the Hopf fibration I mentioned before), but as far as I know doesn't give a general construction for this kind of problems.